# check inputed value with value based on json file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have two `b-form-inputs` the first one will be autofilled from a query string. Now I need to write the `ID` in my other b-form-input and want to check if the `ID` in my json file (based on my `Name`) is equal to my inputed ID.

Than my `validDataAdded: function ()` should return that button will be enabled - this is my problem, i actually don't know how to solve that..

Thank You!

my template:

```
<template>
  <b-card class="mt-5 col-md-6">
    <div class="mt-2">Name</div>
    <b-form-input :disabled="true" v-model="this.Name" :value="this.Name"></b-form-input>
    <div class="mt-4">ID</div>
    <b-form-input type="number"></b-form-input>
    <b-button :disabled="!validDataAdded">Login</b-button>
  </b-card>
</template>
```

my script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "test",
  data() {
    return {
      data: [
        {
        "Name": "Harry",
        "ID": "1234",
        },
        {
        "Name": "Ron",
        "ID": "4321",
        },
        {
        "Name": "Snape",
        "ID": "1973",
        }
      ]
    };
  },

  methods: {

    validDataAdded: function () {
      return //NEED CODE HERE
    }, 
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: And what is your concrete question?

Comment: how to solve this problem - that I check my manual written ```ID``` with the ```ID``` of my ```Name.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you, your property `Name` will be available in your `template` and if someone enters a number in ``, you want to check if your `data` array contains a matching pair of that number and `Name`. If yes, you can try the following:

```
<b-card class="mt-5 col-md-6">
   <div class="mt-2">Name</div>
   <b-form-input :disabled="true" v-model="this.Name" :value="this.Name"></b-form-input>
   <div class="mt-4">ID</div>
   <b-form-input type="number" v-model="this.Number" @keyup="validDataAdded(this.Name, this.Number)"></b-form-input>
   <b-button :disabled="!disabledButton">Login</b-button>
</b-card>
```

For this approach you need two new properties, `disabledButton` and `Number`. `Number` will be the `v-model` of the entered input from the user, so we can use it in `validDataAdded`. This function moved to `b-form-input type="number"` because you need to trigger it. `disabledButton` should be `false` initially.

This would be an example for the function `validDataAdded`:

```
validDataAdded(name, number) {
      Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
        if((this.data[key].Name === name) && (this.data[key].ID === number)) {
          this.disabledButton = true;
        }
      });
    }
```

With passed `name` and `number` it loops trough your `data` and checks if `name` and `number` matches the pair. If yes, `disabledButton` is set to `true`.

Comment: Perfect - it works well! Thanks!